# How to move element on row in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using Webdriver Framework in C# for GUI test automation. 
I have got this sampkle code:

```
univDimM = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[class, 'div']"));
element2=Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@translate='ROW_NAV.CABINET']");
el3 = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@translate='ROW_NAV1.CABINET']"));
    Actions dragdrop = new Actions(Driver);
    dragdrop.Click(univDimM)
        .MoveToElement(element2)
        .ClickAndHold(univDimM)
        .MoveToElement(element2)
        .Release(el3)
        .Build();
        .Perform();
```

Rail/Row has XPath:

```
<ul class="cabinet-module-holders" ng-click="$ctrl.selectCabinetRow({ cabinetRow: $ctrl.cabinetRow })" dnd-list="$ctrl.cabinetRow.modules" dnd-horizontal-list="true" dnd-drop="$ctrl.moveModule(item, $ctrl.cabinetRow, index)" dnd-dragover="$ctrl.moduleDragOver({ cabinetRow: $ctrl.cabinetRow, cabinetRowIndex: index})">
```

In Visual Studio it shows it passed (output window - I use NUnit to run it), but when I open browser and go to web application it does not change. Elements are on cabinet (electricity device) and I want to change power buttons on rows.

Comment: You are referencing a page that we cannot see because you have not provided a link to the page or the HTML sample. You've also not posted any of your code referencing the locators/elements that you are using. NUnit is likely passing because you aren't properly validating the moved element(s). We can't comment on that either because you haven't provided that code.

Comment: OK, I just edited. There is no web app in Internet, it is on our Intranet office network.

Comment: could you explain manual flow?

Comment: I have three rails in UI. In first rail I have universal module and power button. Next, I want to move this element to the second rail by MoveElement() or DragAndDrop().

Comment: Rail has XPath: <ul class="cabinet-module-holders" ng-click="$ctrl.selectCabinetRow({ cabinetRow: $ctrl.cabinetRow })" dnd-list="$ctrl.cabinetRow.modules" dnd-horizontal-list="true" dnd-drop="$ctrl.moveModule(item, $ctrl.cabinetRow, index)" dnd-dragover="$ctrl.moduleDragOver({ cabinetRow: $ctrl.cabinetRow, cabinetRowIndex: index})">

Comment: Click(); is working on rail and each element on the rails. I have problem with DragAndDrop and MoveElement(), because i cannot use pixels position for MoveByOffset(int x, inty);

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have an answer.

```
Actions act = new Actions(Driver);
act.MoveToElement(univDim);
act.Perform();
univDim.DragTo(element3);
```

I have noticed that test developer should put driver element and then DragTo(targetSource).